# Align tables vertically using html

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I align the tables vertically ?

so that

Number 546

Lottery 1

aligns under the column Linked Element

Number 547

Lottery 2

falls under the column Linked Element1

Number 548

Lottery 3

falls under the column Linked Element2

Picture for reference. Turn it for the correct view.
[image]

https://onecompiler.com/html/3zyvupx94

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </=h ead>

  <body>
    <br>
    <html>

    <body>
      <br><br><br>
      <table width="300" table-layout:fixed border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table width="300" table-layout=fixed border="0" rules="none">
              <tr> Linked Element</tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="img_girl.jpg" height="180" width="180" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 546 Lottery 1</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <br>
          <br>
          <td>
            <table width="300" table-layout=fixed border="0" rules="none">
              <tr> Linked Element1</tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="img_girl.jpg" height="180" width="180" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 547 Lottery 1</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <br>
          <br>
          <td>
            <table width="300" table-layout=fixed border="0" rules="none">
              <tr> Linked Element2</tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="img_girl.jpg" height="180" width="180" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 548 Lottery 1</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <br>
          <br>
          <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> Number 546</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> Lottery 1</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> Number 547</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> Lottery 1</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> Number 548</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> Lottery 1</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the lower three tables into table cells that are in a row which still belongs to the "overall table". To create the vertical space, use another `<tr>` in between, with just *one*  `<td>` spanning the whole row which has a defined height (adjust value as needed) and `border: none`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </=h ead>

  <body>
    <br>
    <html>

    <body>
      <br><br><br>
      <table width="300" table-layout:fixed border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table width="300" table-layout=fixed border="0" rules="none">
              <tr> Linked Element</tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="img_girl.jpg" height="180" width="180" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 546 Lottery 1</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table width="300" table-layout=fixed border="0" rules="none">
              <tr> Linked Element1</tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="img_girl.jpg" height="180" width="180" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 547 Lottery 1</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table width="300" table-layout=fixed border="0" rules="none">
              <tr> Linked Element2</tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="img_girl.jpg" height="180" width="180" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 548 Lottery 1</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="height:30px;border:none"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td> Number 546</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> Lottery 1</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td> Number 547</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> Lottery 1</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td> Number 548</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> Lottery 1</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css- Set float:left on the divs so they align horizontally
Add some margin-right space between the divs.

Here is the updated code: https://onecompiler.com/html/3zyvxa8p9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.table-group {
  float: left;  
  margin-right: 50px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="table-group">

<table width="300" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Linked Element</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="300" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Number 546</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lottery 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>

<div class="table-group">

<table width="300" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Linked Element 1</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="300" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Number 547</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
      <td>Lottery 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>

</div>

<div class="table-group">

<table width="300" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Linked Element 2</td>
  </tr>    
</table>

<table width="300" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Number 548</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lottery 3</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

hr {
  margin: 50px 0 30px;
}

.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 600px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}
/* vertical-align-specific styles start here */

td.middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td.top {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td.bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>default vertical alignment for a <code>td</code> is <code>middle</code>.</td>
      <td class="top">vertical-align: top;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="middle">vertical-align: middle;</td>
      <td class="bottom">vertical-align: bottom;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```